# JSP doesn't execute link action

Tags: jsf

I'm struggling with letting JSF execute the action behind a commandLink. It doesn't seem to execute its `action` even though it's not in a form that's nested in another form, there shouldn't be any validation errors and the element seems to be rendered properly.

The page is shows details for a flight booking. The button I'm talking about should take a user to a payment page.

The trouble happens all the way in the back of the form in this file (the messages above don't print anything):

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="metaData">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="departureId" value="#{bookingCreationWizard.departureId}"/>
            <f:viewParam name="returnId" value="#{bookingCreationWizard.returnId}"/>
        </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="pageTitle">#{msg.flights_details_page_title}</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="pageContent">
        <h1>#{msg.flights_details_page_title}</h1>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <h2>#{msg.flight_details_h2_departure}</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Airline</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Seats Remaining</th>
                    <th>Departure Time</th>
                    <th>Flight Duration</th>
                    <th>Arrival Time</th>
                    <th>Departure Airport</th>
                    <th>Arrival Airport</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.flight.airline.name}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.name}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.freeSeats}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.flight.departureTime}</td>
                    <td>TODO</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.flight.arrivalTime}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.flight.departureAirport.code}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.flight.arrivalAirport.code}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.price}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{bookingCreationWizard.hasReturnFlight()}">
            <h2>#{msg.flight_details_h2_return_flight}</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Airline</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Seats Remaining</th>
                    <th>Departure Time</th>
                    <th>Flight Duration</th>
                    <th>Arrival Time</th>
                    <th>Departure Airport</th>
                    <th>Arrival Airport</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.flight.airline.name}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.name}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.freeSeats}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.flight.departureTime}</td>
                    <td>TODO</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.flight.arrivalTime}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.flight.departureAirport.code}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.flight.arrivalAirport.code}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.price}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <h2>#{msg.flight_details_h2_price}</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>#{msg.flight_details_price_table_flight}</th>
                    <th>#{msg.flight_details_price_table_amount}</th>
                    <th>#{msg.flight_details_price_table_total_price}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.flight.departureAirport.code} - #{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.flight.arrivalAirport.code}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.numberOfPeople}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.departureFlight.finalPrice}</td>
                </tr>

                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bookingCreationWizard.hasReturnFlight()}">
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.flight.departureAirport.code} - #{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.flight.arrivalAirport.code}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.numberOfPeople}</td>
                    <td>#{bookingCreationWizard.returnFlight.finalPrice}</td>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </table>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup layout="block">

            <h:form>
                <h:messages style="color:red;margin:8px;"/>
                <h:commandLink action="#{bookingCreationWizard.proceedToPayment()}" value="#{msg.flight_details_booking_button}" />
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Below I've also included the template this file is embedded in, and the @Conversationscoped bean that contains the action that should be executed.

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<f:view locale="#{languageSwitcherController.locale}">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="pageTitle">#{msg.template_title_addon}</ui:insert></title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="normalize.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="skeleton.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css"/>
        <ui:insert name="metaData"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="langauge_form">
            <h:commandLink action="#{languageSwitcherController.changeLanguage('nl_BE')}" value="Nederlands"/> |
            <h:commandLink action="#{languageSwitcherController.changeLanguage('en')}" value="English"/>
        </h:form>

        <!--<h:graphicImage name="01.jpg" library="images" width="500" height="100"/>-->
        <h1>#{msg.template_header}</h1>
        <div>
            <ui:insert name="pageContent">
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
        <br/>
        #{msg.template_footer}
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
@ConversationScoped
@Named
public class BookingCreationWizard implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    @Inject
    private CategoryService service;


    private Long departureId;
    private Long returnId;
    private Category departureFlight;
    private Category returnFlight;
    private int numberOfPeople;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.numberOfPeople = 1;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPeople() {
        return this.numberOfPeople;
    }

    public void setNumberOfPeople(int numberOfPeople) {
        if (conversation.isTransient()){
            conversation.begin();
        }
        this.numberOfPeople = numberOfPeople;
    }

    public Long getDepartureId() {
        return departureId;
    }

    public void setDepartureId(Long departureId) {
        this.departureId = departureId;
    }

    public Long getReturnId() {
        return returnId;
    }

    public void setReturnId(Long returnId) {
        this.returnId = returnId;
    }

    public Category getDepartureFlight() {
        if (departureFlight == null) {
            this.departureFlight = service.getFlightById(this.departureId);
        }
        return this.departureFlight;
    }

    public Category getReturnFlight() {
        if (returnFlight == null) {
            this.returnFlight = service.getFlightById(this.returnId);
        }
        return this.returnFlight;
    }

    public boolean hasReturnFlight() {
        return this.returnId != null;
    }

    public String chooseFlight() {
        return "details.jsf?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String proceedToPayment() {
        System.out.print("Proceeding");
        return "../pay.jsf";
    }
}
```

Comment: please create a [mcve] so everything is fully 'visible' and reproducable. I have, unfortunately for you,  the experience that what posters state is in many case not true. And are you **sure** you are using jsp? I doubt you are.

Comment: It seemed to have been a problem with the first file being in a folder and the target file being above it. Adding 
`<navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>payment</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/payment.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>` to faces config, and making the bean using the payment outcome fixed the problem.